# Most optimal way of starting fresh, without using other theme or dropping old files?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, headers, wp-enqueue-style, customization

I have an unusual situation:
A website with very trashed styles.css (thousands of lines of trashy code), around 70+ custom templates, tons of js libraries loaded.

First reaction was, lets start fresh (since its impossible to fix that tremendous style.css), however the owner says he cannot afford delay and he needs all pages to be working. He understands that things need to be re-done, but it needs to be done in a way that current styles and old pages would stay in tact (as legacy).

So, I am looking for the best way to separate old (lets call it legacy) styling, js and other stuff from main theme files that will be redone one by one. Theoretically I need to make them co-exist in one theme.

Currently I am thinking of having two headers.php, legacy one and new one. In the legacy one I would load all legacy styles directly so they wont be enqueued through functions (there are quite a few there). New header.php would have new styles enqueued through functions as it should.

Problem, old one would still load new styles on top, continuing making the old pages heavier and heavier (plus possible conflicts).

Any better ideas? :/

Comment: Why not develop the new theme in a mirror install and activate it in live site after you have finish it? I think it is really easier and faster to do.

Comment: Ok, problem, 70~ custom tempalate pages, that were designed one by one (no resemblence in some) and the code is burried in one huge style.css.

Comment: I don't know if this is your client, boss, cousin's dog's roommate or whatever but they can't have their cake and eat it too.  If they want things to be re-done, then they need to let you re-do them.  Taking any other approach will likely just result in the same mess a year down the road.  If it's your boss giving you a direct order to do what you can, then I would find out ways to conditionally enqueue styles and js depending on what pages or templates are being loaded.  Then, with your new stuff, you can only load what you need.  A new header.php isn't the end of the world either.